# Django admin - Override red button delete methods in edit screen

Tags: django-admin

I have two models related with a FK like this:

```
class ModelA(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)  
class ModelB(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

So, to delete an instance of ModelA, I have to delete the ModelB instances related to it.
I overrided the delete_selected() method  and it works when I use the admin's bulk delete feature.
But when I edit the ModelA instance, in the admin interface, and click on the red delete button in the "edit screen" it doesn't work.

```
Deleting the ModelA 'first-model-A' would require deleting the following protected related objects:
```

So I also overrided the delete_model() method:

```
def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # here delete ModelB instances related to ModelA instance                
        super(ModelAAdmin, self).delete_model(request, obj)
```

But, it doesn't work...
How can I override the red button delete method ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The point of `on_delete=models.PROTECT`is that it prevents deletion of Model A and it's relations, until it's relations are None. Django ORM will raise an ProtectedError. You cannot delete a Model A instance with a Model B relation.

So the question should be why are you using the protected mechanism?

But if you really need it this way... I would remove the relation of all the Model B objects referencing the Model A instance to a mock-up Model A.

**Later edit:**

Override the 'delete_confirmation.html' template from 'django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html'. I just remove the "{% elif protected %}" part, but you can make to look as you want.

In the admin file have something like:

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        self.delete_confirmation_template = "dummy/admin/dummy/modela/delete_confirmation.html"
        return super(ModelAAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        for modelb_obj in obj.modelb_set.all():
            modelb_obj.delete()
        return super(ModelAAdmin, self).delete_model(request, obj)

admin.site.register(ModelA, ModelAAdmin)
```

Second edit:

Maybe you can try something like:

```
def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    self.delete_confirmation_template = "dummy/admin/dummy/modela/delete_confirmation.html"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ModelB.objects.filter(model_a__id=object_id).delete()
    return super(ModelAAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

Comment: Great idea. But it doesn't work because the delete_view method checks if the object is protected or not before calling delete_model()...  so, I don't know what can I do ?  Edit the _delete_view() method and add an exception for this specific case ?

Comment: Depends on which Django you use. I am using 1.8, and the check of the protected is done after it calls the delete_model function, so for me that worked. But in Django 1.11 they changed the order. They check if it is protected before calling the delete_model function.

Comment: yes, I use django 1.11.  So I give up with `on_delete=models.PROTECT`, I will use CASCADE but I will override delete_view and delete what I want before Django does it... Thank you for your help Dan !

Comment: Great ! It works. Thank you very much Dan. It is regrettable that Django does not handle this case more easily. Thanks again !